# How to remove the edit button of QLPreviewController(swift)?

Tags: swift, qlpreviewcontroller

I'm using QLPreviewController to present PDF files, but there is an edit button on the right of the navigation bar(right top of screen). I don't want the edit button . How can I remove it? I found I can't customize the navigation bar right button of QLPreviewController.

Comment: Try implementing previewController(_,editingModeFor:) although I don’t remember if that won’t let the user edit anyway and save the edits to Files

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable edit button in right side of `NavigationBar` `BarButton`,set delegate of `QLPreviewController` and

Try this delegate method:

```
func previewController(_ controller: QLPreviewController, editingModeFor previewItem: QLPreviewItem) -> QLPreviewItemEditingMode {
    return .disabled }
```

This will hide editing and remove the edit icon next to the search icon.
this is work for me in iOS 15.